# sizeof in function c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I notice two different behaviors when invoking sizeof on primitive array that is not argument of function, and calling it on one that is argument of function.

**Example:**

I have array of six ints (in my codebase, it's much more than that). I am trying to write function that places those ints in `std::vector<std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, int> >`, which means the function must check that the size of the array it's given is multiple of three, before constructing the vector. I test `sizeof a / sizeof a[0]`, right after declaring the int array, and it correctly returns 6. However, when I do:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void doSomething(const int* a)
{
    cout << sizeof a / sizeof a[0] << endl;
    // do some real work down here
}

int main()
{

    int a[] = {40,30,60,38,609,780};
    doSomething(a);
}
```

it does **not** return 6. Why is this happening and what is the quickest and dirtiest way around this unexpected behavior?

Comment: This behavior is very not unexpected. It is giving you the size of a pointer. Take a look at your function. Is that a pointer or is that an array?

Comment: Even if I change the function signature to `void doSomething(const int a[])`, it does the same thing.

Comment: That is because the two are equivalent and mean exactly the same thing. Pass the size of the array as a second parameter. That's the popular practice.

Comment: @DeiDei "popular practice" is to use `std::vector` or `std::array` instead of a raw array.

Comment: @RemyLebeau My bad, for some reason I thought this was tagged as C, not C++. Even then, the right thing to do is often not the popular practice. ;)